# renaming my files from .htm to .php screws up the character encoding..?

Tags: php, html, character-encoding

I was given the job to work in the SEO of a website that is entirely html and javascript. First thing I see, they have hardcoded the headers and the footers(which I want to edit) on every page.

I decided that I want to change all the .htm files to .php in order to take advantage of the php include function and to include the header and the footer as a separate file into every page(yes I know that I could've modify the .htaccess file to treat .htm files as .php but there is a couple of more reasons I wanted .php).

After the change, the special characters on the website started showing as question marks on black background or simply as a normal question mark. When I open the .php files from the cPanel of my host, i see at the top of the editor that encoding is UTF-8 so I don't understand what the problem is. What I do to fix this problem is some kind of "magic" that I hate and it doesn't always work from the first time - copy the code in the whole file, change the encoding to us-ascii, save(at this point the file becomes empty o.O), CLOSE, open back up, paste the code back, tell the editor to open it as utf-8(it creates a new file...), paste the code back in. Then the special characters(like cyrilic, etc.) are displayed properly.

I don't want to do this for as many pages are on the website plus I want to understand the proper way to do it. Anyone can provide any help?

Answer (score 1):

The files encoding must match the charset declared by the HTTP header and the meta tags of your HTML files.

Do you have something like this in your HTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

When you inspect the HTTP headers with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) (or anything else) do you see something like this (watch for "Content-Type"):

```
Response Headers
Date              Thu, 22 Sep 2011 14:53:26 GMT
Server            Apache mod_fcgid/2.3.6 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635
Expires           Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control     private, max-age=10800, pre-check=10800
Content-Language  EN
Last-Modified     Fri, 22 Jul 2011 13:22:29 GMT
Content-Type      text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

When you open the file in your editor and you check it's charset, is it the same as above? Make sur that if you use UTF-8, **no [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)** are added to your files (at least for PHP files).

I guess your editor messed thing up... Can you provide the URL to an actual page? It could help us to tell what's is exactly going on.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, mate!
http://hettahuskies.com/activities/MultiActivity/MAWAW.php
and within the code there is 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
also, the cPanel editor says it is utf-8 encoding.. thanks

Comment: @user959331 This page seems to be in ISO-8859-1 but it's displayed as UTF-8. When I switch to ISO-8859-1, "Pallas-Yll�stunturi National Park" becomes "Pallas-Yllästunturi National Park" (in the "Nature Centre Visit" section).

Comment: @user959331 I converted your page from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 and it works as expected (at least for "Pallas-Yllästunturi National Park"). Your page is either all ISO-8859-1 (but displayed as UTF-8) or your page mixes ISO-8859-1 **and** UTF-8 content (it might be because one include/require is in another charset).

Comment: ha! same as me! thanks! i will see if cyrilic will work and if yes, i will try to just change  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> to <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

Comment: @user959331 And to check if you have an UTF-8 BOM edit your page with an hexadecimal viewer and see if it starts with `EF BB BF`.